# Will facebook app scoped id unlinkable if my token expired?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using my 2 month user token to get "app scoped id" of user.

I am wondering if my user token expire, will the app scoped id disappear or unlinkable?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it won’t. Whether you currently have a valid user access token or not, has no influence on the app-scoped user id.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! Does it depend on the facebook app, like app token? If I use same app to crawl by using different user tokens, it will get same app scoped id of user.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What “crawling” are you talking about?

Comment: @CBroe I mean send request by using facebook graph api. Does the same app with different user token will get same app scoped id for same user?

Comment: Yes, of course. Everything else would not make any sense at all.